# how to automatically center children in css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

my css so I can get the browser width and height:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

this is what I want its' children to center:

```
<div style={{marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto', width: 'inherit', height: 'inherit'}}>
              <ul style={{listStyle: 'none'}}>      
                {this._renderTodos()}
              </ul>
              <Button primary onClick={()=>this._loadMore()}> Load More </Button>
            </div>
```

I wanted the parent div to inherit the browsers' width and height, I used margin left and right equal to auto, but it's not centering?

Comment: Try adding `textAlign: 'center'` :)

Comment: the ul is not centered? but the button is centered

Comment: have to add width on ul . thanks@Dekel

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div is inheriting 100% width from your parent body element, then your ul block element is inheriting the 100% from the parent div.

Try adding a width to your ul and then it will center

```
ul{ width:50%; margin:0 auto; background:purple}
```